# Reading CSS3 Proprieties with jQuery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css, transition

I'm working on an HTML5 slideshow with a jQuery fallback, and I'm having a bit of an issue. I need to find the value of `transition-duration` of `#containter` in all browsers, especially Internet Explorer, since no version supports CSS3 transitions.

I'm using this bit of jQuery to do this, but it doesn't work in IE:

`$('#container').css('transition-duration')`

Is there any way to do this? I think the issue is that IE doesn't even load the CSS value since it's not supported.

Comment: IE10 supports transitions. In older versions you'll need to load the stylesheet via AJAX, then parse the value out to get the value, as properties that aren't supported don't 'stick'.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't seem support the transition property.
Look at this :

```
div
{
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-delay: 2s;
/* Firefox 4 */
-moz-transition-property:width;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
-moz-transition-timing-function:linear;
-moz-transition-delay:2s;
/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transition-property:width;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-transition-delay:2s;
/* Opera */
-o-transition-property:width;
-o-transition-duration:1s;
-o-transition-timing-function:linear;
-o-transition-delay:2s;
}
```

From : http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

But I've just found this :

```
-ms-transition-property,
-ms-transition-duration, 
-ms-transition-timing-function, 
-ms-transition-delay
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466382.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I wrote about this a while ago here: http://focalstrategy.com/blog/2010/08/howto/an-animated-image-slider-that-works-in-internet-explorer/ .

My technique was to trigger the transitions using JS, making it easy to just set the timing values in your JS.

If you want to read the properties, you'll need to load the stylesheet via an XHR, then parse it. That is a pain in the ass for this as to make it robust you'll need to parse the html of the page to get all the stylesheets, and make sure you observe any media queries and @import statements. You'll also need to make sure you follow the cascade and take specitivity into account.

I'd do it the way I do it, it's much more flexible, and still has all the benefits of CSS3 transitions.